# How do stage output variables work in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-services

I have the following piece of YAML code:

```
stages:
  - stage: ApplyDnsPrefixes
    condition: and(succeeded(), ne(dependencies.PlanDnsPrefixes.outputs['PlanDnsPrefixes.COMPUTE_DNS_PREFIXES_PLAN.HAS_ABSENT'], 0))
    variables:
      HAS_ABSENT: $[dependencies.PlanDnsPrefixes.outputs['PlanDnsPrefixes.COMPUTE_DNS_PREFIXES_PLAN.HAS_ABSENT']]
      HAS_ABSENT_1: $[dependencies.PlanDnsPrefixes.PlanDnsPrefixes.outputs['PlanDnsPrefixes.COMPUTE_DNS_PREFIXES_PLAN.HAS_ABSENT']]
      HAS_ABSENT_2: $[dependencies.PlanDnsPrefixes.PlanDnsPrefixes.outputs['COMPUTE_DNS_PREFIXES_PLAN.HAS_ABSENT']]
      HAS_ABSENT_3: $[stageDependencies.PlanDnsPrefixes.outputs['PlanDnsPrefixes.COMPUTE_DNS_PREFIXES_PLAN.HAS_ABSENT']]
      HAS_ABSENT_4: $[stageDependencies.PlanDnsPrefixes.PlanDnsPrefixes.outputs['PlanDnsPrefixes.COMPUTE_DNS_PREFIXES_PLAN.HAS_ABSENT']]
      HAS_ABSENT_5: $[stageDependencies.PlanDnsPrefixes.PlanDnsPrefixes.outputs['COMPUTE_DNS_PREFIXES_PLAN.HAS_ABSENT']]
```

The stage is invoked, so the condition is satisfied. Therefore `dependencies.PlanDnsPrefixes.outputs['PlanDnsPrefixes.COMPUTE_DNS_PREFIXES_PLAN.HAS_ABSENT']` is not zero.

But then trying to set a stage level variable to that value does not work - it produces an empty string!

As you can see, I am trying 6 different variants and then I output the environment using `printenv|sort` command (not shown). All the 6 variants are empty!!!

[image]

What does one have to do to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. So I did not describe it in the question, but now I understand it matters.

There are three stages actually here:

```
PlanDnsPrefixes -> Apply -> ApplyDnsPrefixes
```

In this layout we have 2 implicit direct dependencies:

1. `Apply` depends on `PlanDnsPrefixes`
2. `ApplyDnsPrefixes` depends on `Apply`

However, the dependency I care about is of `ApplyDnsPrefixes` on `PlanDnsPrefixes`, which is an implicit **transitive** dependency and apparently this is not enough for `ApplyDnsPrefixes` to see output variables of `PlanDnsPrefixes`. We must specify the dependency explicitly:

```
    stage: ApplyDnsPrefixes
    dependsOn:
      - PlanDnsPrefixes
      - Apply
    condition: and(succeeded(), ne(dependencies.PlanDnsPrefixes.outputs['PlanDnsPrefixes.COMPUTE_DNS_PREFIXES_PLAN.HAS_ABSENT'], 0))
    variables:
      ABSENT_DNS_PREFIXES: $[stageDependencies.PlanDnsPrefixes.PlanDnsPrefixes.outputs['COMPUTE_DNS_PREFIXES_PLAN.ABSENT']]
    displayName: Apply DNS Prefixes
```

I find it confusing that `condition` and `variables` refer to the same output variable differently.